# Best time to invalidate NSTimer inside UIViewController to avoid retain cycle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, nstimer

Does any one know when is the best time to stop an NSTimer that is held reference inside of a UIViewController to avoid retain cycle between the timer and the controller?

Here is the question in more details: I have an NSTimer inside of a UIViewController.

During ViewDidLoad of the view controller, I start the timer:

```
statusTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1 target: self selector: @selector(updateStatus) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

The above causes the timer to hold a reference to the view controller.

Now I want to release my controller (parent controller releases it for example)

the question is: where can I put the call to [statusTimer invalidate] to force the timer to release the reference to the controller?

I tried putting it in ViewDidUnload, but that does not get fired until the view receives a memory warning, so not a good place. I tried dealloc, but dealloc will never get called as long as the timer is alive (chicken & egg problem).

Any good suggestions?

Comment: There is no need to retain the view controller in the timer. The VC should own the timer, like any other object it would own, and destroy it when appropriate.

Comment: @logancautrell, you have a good point, but `NSTimer` retains the target you pass to it and that cannot be changed. (Some of the answers suggest ways to try and work around that though.)

Comment: Yikes, I see the problem you are running into. An alternative is to add a helper object that both your VC and the timer own.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. You could *avoid the retain cycle* to begin with by, e.g., aiming the timer at a `StatusUpdate` object that holds a non-retained (weak) reference to your controller, or by having a `StatusUpdater` that is initialized with a pointer your controller, holds a weak reference to that, and sets up the timer for you.

   - You could *have the view stop the timer in `-willMoveToWindow:`* when the target window is `nil` (which should handle the counterexample to `-viewDidDisappear:` that you provided) as well as in `-viewDidDisappear:`. This does mean your view is reaching back into your controller; you could avoid reaching in to grab the timer by just send the controller a `-view:willMoveToWindow:` message or by posting a notification, if you care.
   - Presumably, you're the one causing the view to be removed from the window, so you could *add a line to stop the timer alongside the line that evicts the view.*
   - You could *use a non-repeating timer.* It will invalidate as soon as it fires. You can then test in the callback whether a new non-repeating timer should be created, and, if so, create it. The unwanted retain cycle will then only keep the timer and controller pair around till the next fire date. With a 1 second fire date, you wouldn't have much to worry about.

Every suggestion but the first is a way to live with the retain cycle and break it at the appropriate time. The first suggestion actually avoids the retain cycle.

Comment: I prefer using a non-repeating timer and recreating in the callback.

Comment: I think using `viewWillMovetoWindow:` is the best solution when using a custom view class that has the timer, and when the view controller (VC) using it doesn't hold a reference to that view class. Consider the case where dynamic views get initialized in a VC; the VC has no explicit way to tell the view class to invalidate its timer when `viewWillDisappear:` gets called. It could iterate through its views and create a `cleanup` method on its view class or use an `NSNotification`, but I think `willMoveToWindow:` is the cleanest. Don't think the non-repeating timer suggestion would work here.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei As OP points out, there's a chicken and egg problem: While a timer is retaining its target, its target will not dealloc. If its target expects to invalidate the timer retaining it in dealloc, then it will never invalidate it, because the timer is keeping it from deallocing! If it's still unclear, I recommend asking a new, full question.

Comment: @JeremyW.Sherman, But it doesn't look like this is the case, since I use `dealloc` in `UIViewController`s to deallocate timers and it worked ok. Isn't in fact your overwritten `dealloc` called prior to any `NSObject` deallocation? What is `dealloc` even used for, then? If not manually deallocing the respective object's properties?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Please [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with some example source code to make the discussion concrete. The short answer is "because retain (aka strong reference) cycles in the common case where the timer's target is also its owner".

Comment: @JeremyW.Sherman, Did it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358646/invalidate-nstimer-in-dealloc).

Answer (score 6):

One way around it is to make the NStimer hold a weak reference to your UIViewController. I created a class that holds a weak reference to your object and forwards the calls to that:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface WeakRefClass : NSObject

+ (id) getWeakReferenceOf: (id) source;

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation;

@property(nonatomic,assign) id source;

@end

@implementation WeakRefClass

@synthesize source;

- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
//    if (self) {
//    }
    return self;
}

+ (id) getWeakReferenceOf: (id) _source{

    WeakRefClass* ref = [[WeakRefClass alloc]init];
    ref.source = _source; //hold weak reference to original class

    return [ref autorelease];
}

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    return [[self.source class ] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation
{
    [anInvocation    invokeWithTarget:self.source ];

}

@end
```

and you use it like this:

```
statusTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1 target: [WeakRefClass getWeakReferenceOf:self] selector: @selector(updateStatus) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

Your  dealloc method  gets called (unlike before) and inside it you just call:

```
[statusTimer invalidate];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated` and then you should validate it again in `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`

[More here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW17)

Comment: when inside a UINavigationController, viewDidDisappear does not gets called, so I'm looking for a more general place to put it, also when I hide the view using [self.view removeFromSuperview], viewDidDisappear does not get called either.

Comment: what do you mean by inside a UINavigationController. when you pop it out? Can you post some more code about that

Answer (score 2):

For **@available(iOS 10.0, *)** you could also use:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(
    withTimeInterval: 1,
    repeats: true,
    block: { [weak self] _ in
        self?.updateStatus()
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [-viewDidDisappear](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidDisappear:) method may be what you're looking for. It's called whenever the view is hidden or dismissed.

Comment: But viewDidDisappear never gets called when I hide my parent view using: [self.view removeFromSuperview].

Any other suggestion?

Comment: In addition, when inside a UINavigationController, viewDidDisappear does not gets called, so I'm looking for a more general place to put it.

Comment: viewDidDisappear would be perfect if one could rely on it always being called, unfortunately this is not the case

Answer (score 1):

invalidate timer inside - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated did work for me

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a "weak reference" class for exactly this reason. It subclasses NSObject, but forwards all methods that NSObject doesn't support to a target object. The timer retains the weakref, but the weakref doesn't retain its target, so there's no retain cycle.

The target calls [weakref clear] and [timer invalidate] or so in dealloc. Icky, isn't it?

(The next obvious thing is to write your own timer class that handles all of this for you.)

Answer (score 0):

If the timer.REPEAT is set to `YES`, the owner of the timer (e.g. view controller or view) will not be deallocated until the timer is invalidated.

**The solution to this question is to find some trigger point to stop your timer.**

For example, I start a timer to play animated GIF images in a view, and the trigger point would be:

1. when the view is added to the superview, start the timer
2. when the view is removed from the superview, stop the timer

so I choose the `UIView`'s `willMoveToWindow:` method as such:

```
- (void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow {
    if (self.animatedImages && newWindow) {
        _animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:_animationInterval
            target:self selector:@selector(drawAnimationImages)
            userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    } else {
        [_animationTimer invalidate];
        _animationTimer = nil;
    }
}
```

If your timer is owned by a ViewController, maybe `viewWillAppear:` and `viewWillDisappear:` are a good place for you to start and stop the timer.

Answer (score -2):

I had exactly the same issue and in the end I decided to override the release method of the View Controller to look for the special case of the retainCount being 2 and my timer running.  If the timer wasn't running then this would have caused the release count to drop to zero and then call dealloc.

```
- (oneway void) release {
    // Check for special case where the only retain is from the timer
    if (bTimerRunning && [self retainCount] == 2) {
        bTimerRunning = NO;
        [gameLoopTimer invalidate];
    }
    [super release];
}
```

I prefer this approach because it keeps it simple and encapsulated within the one object, i.e., the View Controller and therefore easier to debug.  I don't like, however, mucking about with the retain/release chain but I cannot find a way around this.

Hope this helps and if you do find a better approach would love to hear it too.

Dave

EDIT: Should have been  -(oneway void)

Answer (score -3):

You can write this code in dealloc function of view controller

for eg.

```
-(void)dealloc
{
   if([statusTimer isValid])
  {
       [statusTimer inValidate];
       [statustimer release];
      statusTimer = nil;
  }
}
```

this way the reference counter of statustimer will automatically decrement by 1
& also the data on the allocated memory will also erase

also you can write this code in `- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated` function

Comment: -1 The problem is that `dealloc` will never be called because the `NSTimer` is keeping the `UIViewController` alive.