# iOS - Popping UIViewController doesn't destroy its properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

When I pop a `UIViewController` instance off of my `UINavigationController`, I find that its properties remain (`NSTimers` keep timing, `AVAudioPlayers` keep playing, etc.).  I'm wondering what's wrong with my approach?

I push the UIViewController instance onto the UINavigationController this way:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    UINavigationController *nc=[self navigationController];
    NewViewController *nvc=[[NewViewController alloc] init];
    [nvc setNameToUse:[self nameToUse]];
    [nc pushViewController:nvc2 animated:YES];
}
```

The NewViewController has a sub-viewcontroller, that is added via NiewViewController's viewDidLoad method:

```
self.mySubViewController=[[SubViewViewController alloc] initWithName:self.nameToUse];
self.mySubViewController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,
                                           0,
                                           self.mySubViewController.view.frame.size.width,
                                           self.mySubViewController.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:self.mySubViewController.view];
```

It's the properties of SubViewController that don't go away when NewViewController is popped.  One of these in particular is a timer, declared as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSTimer *aTimer;
```

Any advice on this would be terrific.  I'm hoping that by solving this issue, the crashes that have been happening once in a while (after the app has been running for 45 or so minutes) will stop!  Or at least I'll have a better idea of what's causing them...  :) Thanks for reading.

Comment: Instead of making `mySubViewController` a property of your view controller try adding it as a child view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I did do this, but it was my usage of NSTimer which was the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSTimer` retains it's target, if you are passing self (your `SubViewViewController`) then you'll be creating a retain cycle between the view controller and the timer.

Comment: Yup, that appears to be it!  I temporarily dropped the timer and now the AVAudioPlayer stops playing when NewViewController is popped.  Is there an alternative way to use the timer that won't cause the retain cycle?

Comment: This thread appears to be exactly what I need:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478361/best-time-to-invalidate-nstimer-inside-uiviewcontroller-to-avoid-retain-cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding SubViewController's view to ViewController's will not correctly pass events.

You need to correctly implement UIViewController child containment, as such:

So your second code block should be something like:

```
[self addChildViewController:self.mySubViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.mySubViewController.view];
[self.mySubViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: Thanks for this, happy to learn about the right way to do this!