# xcode, how to destroy/release/dismiss previous controller/scene after popviewcontrolleranimated

Tags: objective-c, xcode, popviewcontrolleranimated

i had 2 scene, "List Scene" and "Details Scene". After Click the Item on "List Scene", it will go to "Details Scene". In the "Details Scene", i had some animation, anime the Image keep repeat move from left to right or right to left. After i go back "List Scene", the scene looking like "hanging", i cant do any thing for the List any more(like scrolling). After i check out, found out the "Left to Right,Right To Left" animation is still running on behind. So now i assume, because the previous scene i still running, so current scene not able to detect my finger.

so my question is, is that got any way can remove/release/dismiss the previous scene after popviewcontrolleranimated?
below is the code i testing now.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(Bool)animated{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
self.imagePanViewController = nil; //target is this viewcontroller, this viewcontroller handle the animation
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

i had try use some way like "dismissViewController", release, controller = nil, and so on. but the results is still fail and animation keep running on behind.

is that any one can give me some guideline or hints? thanks alot!

Comment: Not clear. Please add the source for "Left to Right,Right To Left" animation

Comment: @bllakjakk, the animation source is combine it many file and class. is that really need put all at here? i though got some way to destroy/release/dismiss whole viewcontroller whatever how the viewcontroller inside?

Answer (score 0):

I believe myidleTimer is an NSTimer. NSTimer retains its target.
You can follow the below link to properly invalidate it
[Best time to invalidate NSTimer inside UIViewController to avoid retain cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478361/best-time-to-invalidate-nstimer-inside-uiviewcontroller-to-avoid-retain-cycle)

Also make the timer having weak reference.

Comment: i had update the code, sorry for misdirection. the "myidleTimer" had stoped. just the problem is the "self.imagePanViewController", because the this ViewController still running on behind even i on "List Scene".