# Invalidating an NSTimer in dealloc

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management, nstimer, dealloc

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3478361/865175), and more specifically, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478361/best-time-to-invalidate-nstimer-inside-uiviewcontroller-to-avoid-retain-cycle/3792082?noredirect=1#comment65111668_3792082):

> because retain (aka strong reference) cycles in the common case where the timer's target is also its owner

I am wondering why `dealloc` isn't a good place to invalidate an `NSTimer`.

I remember profiling my app without auto-repeating `NSTimer` invalidation and then with invalidation in `dealloc`, and the memory correctly freed.

Is `dealloc` working differently in the latest iOS?

Isn't in fact your overridden `dealloc` called prior to any `NSObject` deallocation? What is `dealloc` even used for, then? If not manually deallocating the respective object's properties?

Comment: NSTimer is Retaining your object, because of this reason, Dealloc will never be called ( thus NSTimer invalidated )

Comment: the `-dealloc` method is being invoked by the system _when_ the system wants to deallocate a released object, you cannot rely on _when_ that actually happens while the timer is still running; on the other hand you can could make accidentally a strong retain cycle when the `-dealloc` will never be triggered, and your timer would be also stuck in background doing a task which you don't need to anymore, which may lead inconsistent behaviour or even crash, but definitely makes your app a bad memory citizen.

Comment: Isn't `UIViewController`'s `dealloc` called after you call `dismissViewController:animated:`?

Comment: no, dealloc is called after its not retained ( pointed ) anywhere else

Comment: I will run some Profiling again and try to understand what was happening.

Comment: Indeed, this is correct, as [this page](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/311831-arc-and-dealloc.html) says it too. @ogres, Care to post an answer to accept it as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC will only release ( and call `dealloc` ) objects, when there are no `strong` references pointing to this object ( no one is retaining ).

`NSTimer` creates `strong` reference and it will retain `target`.

This means, `dealloc` will not be called, because NSTimer still has `strong` reference to the object. If there is no `dealloc`, this means `NSTimer` will never be invalidated ... leads to memory leak or even crashes.

There is a way to `invalidate` timer in `dealloc` or when `target` becomes nil. Have a look at the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16822471/1824510).